# What connector is this?

Tags: hard-drive

The drive was pulled from my old ibm laptop (thinkpad variant) I dont remember the model number because i had to pitch it when i was packing to move.

So i have a couple questions:

1) What connector is needed for it?

2) what connector is it?

3) is there any hardware to connect to it? (external drive connectors)

4) How old is it?

5) what brand of IBM thinkpad most likely used it?

also: please dont mind i took the pictures over my bathroom sink

[image: enter link description here]

[The images of the harddrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgddM.jpg)

Comment: It's an enclosure you do know that right?

Comment: i know it is an enclosure, of which i am worried about opening, just was wondering about the interface.

Answer (score 4):

All this information was ascertained from the inscription on the hard drive caddy itself: 34.43B27.XXXR01

This hard drive (inside a caddy) is for a ThinkPad 390.

The item you took pictures of is a hard drive caddy. It is a specialized enclosure where a hard drive fits into.

The specs on how to remove a hard drive is on page 63 of this [ThinkPad 390 service manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/37l5153.pdf)

[image: Page 63 of IBM ThinkPad 390 Service Manual]

Comment: Thats interesting, and eh, I guess my thinkpads arn't that old. Its cool that Lenovo still keeps manuals for such old systems around, and that IBM used these shims too

Comment: [IBM sold their PC business in 2004 to Lenovo](http://news.cnet.com/IBM-sells-PC-group-to-Lenovo/2100-1042_3-5482284.html). It is common to find older IDE laptops in caddies because of the pins. If the pins got bent because you pushed the hard drive in wrong, you just wasted a lot of time and money. This is not an issue with newer SATA drives, but you know there's a backstory to why these hard drive caddies came into use during that decade.

Comment: Oh, I have probably one of the last *actual* IBM models (that was sata) and a slightly newer thinkpad which didn't have a caddy, but had PATA. It was a significantly simmer drive if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It is a type of IDE with 44 pins.
here is the pic of connector removed
 4 pins on the right side are the jumper settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite a few thinkpads - I think they switched over from pata to sata around the R/T/X 60 era, since that's sata, and my old R51 was pata. So, this is approximately Pentium M era or much earlier, but before the core solos and duos. Thinkpads generally didn't use these shims over 44 pin connectors - every thinkpad I have seen with an oldschool sata drive had it plugged in directly. The caddy style also seems unfamiliar to me, thinkpads generally had perforated caddies with round holes.

I *have* however seen an identical shim converting a 44 pin hard drive to some flavour of edge connector on a Dell, which is what I suspect this is from. I suspect its sole purpose is to make installation easier, and cut down on bent pins. Without the original laptop its entirely useless and you can pitch it

If you look around, any pata compatible 2.5 inch IDE->USB connector would do. There's probably also 44 -> 40+molex converters. You may be able to use a PATA->Sata converter too, and there's designs that work specifically between 44 pin pata to sata.

However considering the age of this drive, You're probably better off getting the data  out to a more modern drive than using it