# Female to male adapter to copy data from Dell Insipiron laptop model PP12L hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I need to transfer data from hard drive removed from Dell Insipiron Model PP12L. 
The connector on the hard drive is 44 pin strip-like. It has no pins. The connections are flat, arrow-like copper pieces molded into a plastic stip. I need an adapter from female 44 pin strip-like to a 44 pin IDE male connector. 
Where can I find it? What is a proper name for this adapter?

Thank you in advance, Adam W,

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/811453/what-connector-is-this/811466#811466 is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

All drives are made the same to avoid this sort of problem. All PATA drives have 40 or 44 male pins. I would suspect that if yours doesn't look like one of [these](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=123149&d=1363114417) or [this](http://bixnet.net/images/HDD35-40-PinIDE.jpg) then you're probably looking at a drive and an IDE connector which has been forcibly removed and broken. From your description, it may also be that you have a SATA drive and a PATA motherboard. If that is the case then you need [an adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004ETGOCG) if this is going to work. I have no experience using these though.

Answer (score 0):

First off are you sure it has 44 pins? "flat, arrow-like copper pieces molded into a plastic stip" sounds like a SATA connector but a SATA power+data connector only has 22 pins, 7 on the data part and 15 on the power part.

If it is a SATA connector then you can just hook it up to a desktop PC with a normal SATA controller and cabling.

If it is not a SATA connector then I would look carefully at the drive to see if it looks like there is a removable adapter attatched. It used to be quite common to see a stadnard laptop IDE drive with a laptop-specific adapter attatched.

Failing both of those you will need to post a picture before we can advise further.